# Realtime(ish) updates on Web Page using AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, jinja2

I'm using AppEngine to create a page that I would like to update from the program. Specifically, I am getting some market data and would like to have a table (or something else appropriate) that shows current prices. Let me be clear: I am new to this and think my problem is that I'm not asking the question well enough to find a good (best) answer. I'm not even sure AppEngine is necessarily the way to go. I'll also caveat that I've been learning via Udacity so if code looks familiar -- kudos to Steve Huffman.

I've created the page via jinja2 and I've managed to wrangle the appropriate libraries and sandbox parameters to get market updates. I've created an html table and passed in a dictionary with values for exchanges and bid/ask pairs. The table creates fine -- but when I render again, I get tables repeating down the page rather than one table with updating market prices.

Here is the html/jinja2 (I ditched all the styling to make it shorter):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Table template</h1>
    <table>
      {% for exch in mkt_data %}
      <tr>
        <td> <div>{{exch}}</div></td>
        <td> <div>{{mkt_data[exch][0]}}</div></td>
        <td><div>{{mkt_data[exch][1]}}</div></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import ccxt

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                                autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("table.html", mkt_data=btc)
        for x in range(3):
            for exch in exchanges:
                orderbook=exch.fetch_order_book('BTC/USD')
                bid = orderbook['bids'][0][0] if len(orderbook['bids'])>0 else None
                ask = orderbook['asks'][0][0] if len(orderbook['asks'])>0 else None
                btc[exch.id]=[bid,ask]
                self.render("table.html", mkt_data=btc)


gdax = ccxt.gdax()
gemini = ccxt.gemini()

exchanges = [gdax, gemini]
btc = {"gemini":[0,1], "gdax":[1,2]}
for exch in exchanges:
    exch.load_markets()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I have 2 questions:
First, why am I getting the table repeating? I think I know why, but I want to hear a formal reason.
Second, what *should* I be doing? I originally started learning javascript/node but then it seemed very hard to wrap all the appropriate libraries (was looking into browserify but then thought appengine may be better so I could more easily host something for others to see). I tried integrating some javascript but that did not get me anywhere. Now I've run into Firebase but before I go learn yet another "thing" I wanted to ask how other people do this. I'm certain there are multiple ways but I'm new to web programming; I'm viewing a web page as a nice UI & delivery mechanism.

Some add'l notes: using Ubuntu, virtualenv, ccxt library (for cryptocurrency).

edit: I checked Dan's answer because it offered a solution. I'd love to hear about whether Firebase is "a" more correct solution rather than auto-refreshing.

Comment: Please, create a separate post for the second quesiton and edit this one accordingly.

Comment: Also it didn't seem to be directly related to google-app-engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeated table is the result of the multiple `self.render()` calls inside your `MainPage.get()` - both above and repetead ones inside the `for` loop(s).

Update your code to make a single such call, after the `for` loops building the template values (at the end of `MainPage.get()`)

Comment: thx @dan. so then, render does not do a complete re-draw. then how would i provide updates to the values?

Comment: just provide updated values to fill the template with at the next request. Eventually make your page auto-refreshing (on the client side - the browser would automatically issue subsequent requests)

Comment: You can't modify the response after the response to the initial request is sent - the request context is lost

Comment: thx again, Dan. I implemented auto-refresh and it worked. However, that is not a "correct" solution for the long run. Any feedback on Firebase or something else?

Comment: I didn't use Firebase yet. Maybe make a smarter page, using JS on client side to make AJAX requests in the background and update page elements with the data received? Then you wouldn't need to reload the entire page.